# JavaFX setAlwaysOnTop on a fullscreen stage

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a main stage with these properties. It is meant to be a secure "lockdown stage"

```
    public static Stage getSecureStage(Window window) throws IOException {

    Stage stage = new Stage();

    //Take up the entire screen boundaries
    Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    stage.setHeight(visualBounds.getHeight());
    stage.setWidth(visualBounds.getWidth());

    //Secure the stage
    stage.setFullScreen(true);
    stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
    stage.setFullScreenExitHint(null);
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

    stage.setScene(getScene(window));
    return stage;
}
```

With this lockdown stage, I want to be able to have popup windows within the stage stay on top

[image]

As you can see, the stage initializes on top of the lockdown stage. However, if I am to click off of that popup and back onto the main lockdown stage, the lockdown stage takes priority and puts itself over the popup. It does not minimize it, but just goes on top.

I have given the popup the properties

```
popup.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
popup.initOwner(lockdownStage);
```

however, that does not seem to do the trick. I had not previously had this issue running on Linux, with the same code. Please let me know if you need anymore information

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by getting rid of the

```
stage.setFullScreen(true);
stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
stage.setFullScreenExitHint(null);
```

and setting it instead to

```
stage.setMaximized(true);
```

With the previous fullscreen setup, you could also use the `stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);` on the popup window. In my case, I wanted to be able to interact with both windows not singling one out with the modality feature.